# How can I hide the CommandField when the user is not logged in? ASP.net VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a GridView on the main page of my website. I want to hide the first column which is:

This is the grid view.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource4" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical" Height="300px" Width="1265px" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" SelectText="Add to Cart"></asp:CommandField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ID_CARTE" HeaderText="Id" SortExpression="ID_CARTE" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hide-th" ItemStyle-CssClass="hide-td" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Titlu" HeaderText="Titlu" SortExpression="Titlu" />
            </Columns>
```

This is the login page code. I must hide the column because it contains a button which is adding items in the ShoppingCart and I want the user to be able to add items only when it's logged in.

```
 Protected Sub LogIn(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        If IsValid Then
            ' Validate the user password
            Dim manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager(Of ApplicationUserManager)()
            Dim signinManager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager(Of ApplicationSignInManager)()

            ' This doen't count login failures towards account lockout
            ' To enable password failures to trigger lockout, change to shouldLockout := True
            Dim result = signinManager.PasswordSignIn(Email.Text, Password.Text, RememberMe.Checked, shouldLockout := False)

            Select Case result
                Case SignInStatus.Success
                    If Request.QueryString("ReturnUrl") Is Nothing Then
                        IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl("/Carti", Response)
                    Else
                        IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl(Request.QueryString("ReturnUrl"), Response)
                    End If
```

Comment: Start with the column not visible. After log-in, find the column and set it to visible. Search SO for how to show/hide a column from code-behind.

Answer (score 0):

Start with the column not visible. After log-in, find the column and set it to visible. Basically:

```
GridView.Columns[0].Visible = true;
```

If needed, search SO for how to show/hide a column from code-behind.